# Adding special fields to confluence page via Wiki Rest API

Tags: wiki, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am creating a new confluence page via a content/post api call. So far so good.
Unfortunately confluence api doesn't support creating a new page out of an existing template.
I managed to create headers and a table, and know how to inject html content.

The problem is:
I didn't find any solution online to create more complex content. Specically: a date field (I want it to be presented the same way a date field is presented when you manually create it by '//' - it is presented as a formatted date, and if you edit the document - you can edit it through a "date picker" (choosing from a calendar).
Also I want to add "instructional text" (this is the name when creating a template manually) - text that appears only on edit mode (some descriptions for each section, that don't appear on the doc it self, but do appear on edit - like a placeholder), and don't know how I can do it through the api.

My current json body (Which works fine for these simple types) is:

```
{
  body: {
    wiki: {
      representation: "wiki",
      value: "h1. some title name h1. another title ||tableCol||anothertablecol||.... {html}<somehtmltag />{html}"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add a date field (date picker) and an instructional text?
Didn't find any relevant real documentation for the wiki representation syntax.

Thanks in advance